# Bootstrap side view went to bottom in small screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

I create a simple content and side view with bootstrap. the side bar placed in the right side of the website but in the small screen it went to the bottom of the website. I don't know how can I fix it

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">

            <div class="bg-light p-3 mt-4">
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ab accusantium alias aperiam cumque delectus earum, eligendi eos eveniet excepturi, exercitationem harum iste itaque iure laborum molestias mollitia, neque nesciunt nihil nostrum numquam perspiciatis qui sed sequi voluptatibus. Aliquid blanditiis, commodi corporis culpa delectus dignissimos, doloribus enim inventore nobis numquam omnis tempora ullam vel. Architecto doloribus dolorum ex fugiat impedit qui veritatis. Dolorum, in ipsum nisi quas similique sint tempore. Ab accusamus asperiores consequuntur culpa cupiditate debitis deserunt dolore doloribus dolorum eius enim eos error esse impedit ipsa iusto labore laboriosam magni maxime, minima modi natus perspiciatis placeat quibusdam quo quos rerum saepe sunt ullam veritatis? Adipisci autem cumque debitis dignissimos dolorum eaque est eum, expedita facere fuga in iusto minima numquam odio, odit officiis perferendis, placeat quia quisquam ratione ullam unde ut. Accusamus atque dignissimos doloremque harum modi neque repudiandae sed? A ab aliquid, animi aut consequuntur dicta dolores ducimus eos, exercitationem ipsam iusto magnam minima neque nesciunt obcaecati odio officia saepe temporibus unde voluptatem. Aliquam assumenda aut blanditiis consectetur cupiditate delectus earum eveniet facilis id ipsa ipsam, iure non quae quas quia, quo repellat reprehenderit tenetur, velit vitae! Atque beatae corporis ipsum nemo, rem reprehenderit unde vitae voluptatum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light p-3 mt-4"><!-- post will added here with php -->
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ab accusantium alias aperiam cumque delectus earum, eligendi eos eveniet excepturi, exercitationem harum iste itaque iure laborum molestias mollitia, neque nesciunt nihil nostrum numquam perspiciatis qui sed sequi voluptatibus. Aliquid blanditiis, commodi corporis culpa delectus dignissimos, doloribus enim inventore nobis numquam omnis tempora ullam vel. Architecto doloribus dolorum ex fugiat impedit qui veritatis. Dolorum, in ipsum nisi quas similique sint tempore. Ab accusamus asperiores consequuntur culpa cupiditate debitis deserunt dolore doloribus dolorum eius enim eos error esse impedit ipsa iusto labore laboriosam magni maxime, minima modi natus perspiciatis placeat quibusdam quo quos rerum saepe sunt ullam veritatis? Adipisci autem cumque debitis dignissimos dolorum eaque est eum, expedita facere fuga in iusto minima numquam odio, odit officiis perferendis, placeat quia quisquam ratione ullam unde ut. Accusamus atque dignissimos doloremque harum modi neque repudiandae sed? A ab aliquid, animi aut consequuntur dicta dolores ducimus eos, exercitationem ipsam iusto magnam minima neque nesciunt obcaecati odio officia saepe temporibus unde voluptatem. Aliquam assumenda aut blanditiis consectetur cupiditate delectus earum eveniet facilis id ipsa ipsam, iure non quae quas quia, quo repellat reprehenderit tenetur, velit vitae! Atque beatae corporis ipsum nemo, rem reprehenderit unde vitae voluptatum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">

            <div class="bg-light p-3 mt-4">
                <h2>Head</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, sed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light p-3 mt-4">
                <h2>Head</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, sed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's responsive, where do you want it to go?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for here. In a smaller screen, side-by-side bootstrap components are designed to go one below the other. Thats just how responsiveness works. If you add a screenshot maybe, we can better understand the question and what you are looking to fix.

Comment: @sidx63 Suppose we have for example 15 post in a single page. Users should scroll to the bottom of page for choosing side bar items. Is that a good idea ?

Comment: @mxmissile The side bar is not post . It is for using items like category tag and etc